# Why is selinux blocking root from enabling iptables?

Tags: centos, selinux

As root, on CentOS 7

```
systemctl enable iptables
```

prints

```
Failed to execute operation: Access denied
```

Here is a screenshot of what gets put in `audit.log`

[image]

I take this to mean selinux is blocking me, even though I am root. Does this audit log explain why? If not, where else should I look?

Answer (score 0):

Although `iptables` was installed, I also needed to install `iptables-services` and `policycoreutils-python`.